# Why does the following day remainder logic return the incorrect result?

Tags: kotlin, date, datetime, math, duration

I am attempting to calculate the number of days and weeks left-over in the current year in Kotlin. To do this I've implemented the following:

```
val dateDiff = Duration.between(LocalDate.of(1952, 10, 5).atStartOfDay(), LocalDate.of(2022, 11, 28).atStartOfDay())
val leftOverDays = dateDiff.toDays().rem(365F)
val leftOverWeeks = leftOverDays.div(7F)
```

This has the following output:

```
dateDiff.toDays() = 25621
leftOverDays = 71
leftOverWeeks = 10.142858
```

However, if you use any other website to do the same calculation, [such as this one](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=10&d1=5&y1=1952&m2=11&d2=28&y2=2022), the result is:

> It is 25,621 days from the start date to the end date, but not
> including the end date. Or 70 years, 1 month, 23 days excluding the
> end date.

Note that while the total days are identical, the remainder in the current year (**1 month, 23 days**) is not the same as my remainder (**71 days**). Mine is ~20 days more, almost an extra 3 weeks.

What is wrong with my math?

Comment: leap years  :) dividing by 365 ?

Comment: `Duration` is for a difference in *time* and unsuited for days, weeks, months and years. By contrast `Period` is a difference in the calendar, years and months and days and cannot handle hours and smaller.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you haven't calculated the leap year.
You can divide be 365.25 but might not be accurate for long years .Also it might come in decimals.

Try this instead for exact value,

```
val startDate = LocalDate.of(1952, 10, 5).atStartOfDay().toLocalDate()
val endDate = LocalDate.of(2022, 11, 28).atStartOfDay().toLocalDate()
val period = Period.between(startDate,endDate)
println("Years : ${period.years}  , Months: ${period.months} , Days: ${period.days}")
```

**Edit:**
As Ole V.V's comment,
You can even leave out `atStartOfDay`.

```
val startDate = LocalDate.of(1952, 10, 5)
val endDate = LocalDate.of(2022, 11, 28)
```

[image]